# Efficient way to count number of pages to print?

Tags: c#, printing

**TLDR**
How can one efficiently determine the amount of pages that have to be printed?

** Just a note: I marked klugerama's answer as the answer to my question. I'm still open for other suggestions though!

Currently, I have an application in production which prints invoices. The printing itself isn't a problem: customer information, invoice details etc are printed as they should be. However, users are complaining about the time it takes my software to send the print job to the printer.

At the moment, I have implemented a rather inefficient way to print. In order to know how many pages I have to print, I do a 'dry run' of the print job and cancel it before it gets sent to the printer. Then I count the number of pages the print job contains and add that information to the print job that actually does get sent to the printer. To do this, I 'abuse' the [PrintDocument.PrintPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method. After doing so, I can print "Page 1/2 - Page 2/2" etc.

I'm currently thinking about handling this in a different way. I know which margins I have in a page, like the header and the footer. Ergo, the space between header and footer is the available space to print article information (name, price etc). If I calculate the height of the string (using [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)), I can tell when the articles take up more space on a page that's available for printing.

Previously, printing could take up to a minute before actually getting sent to the printer (taken into account the clients which run the software aren't the fastest around). I have implemented this method, and printing now takes about 5-10 seconds. However, I'm wondering if this is the way to go. I can't imagine I'm the only one dealing with this issue; how do you deal with this?

I'm also open to completely different approaches.

Comment: Perhaps you could prerender it in pdf or xps ans just Count the pages of the document.

Comment: @Grumbler85 That would be an option, but generating the PDF/XPS would probably take as much time as doing a dry run of the print job. I do have my doubts about your approach, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Since most Printers today are capable of printing pdf and XPs directly there is a Chance, that you do not loose much time...

Comment: @Grumbler85 true, but I'm wondering how to determine the amount of pages to print, because I want to show that on the sheet that I want to print (Page 1/2 - Page 2/2 etc), and not in a footer as you would do with Microsoft Word. I'd still be stuck with doing a dry run, count the pages, cancel the printing and send the actual print job to the printer. Or am I thinking too much in my own solution?

Comment: You want to Show a "currently printing page 1/2" on Screen or on paper?

Comment: @Grumbler85 on paper. I don't want to bug users with printing messages. They click on a print button and the invoice should print, without any feedback from my GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing sounds like the way to go. But...

You could instead output to XML and use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) to style the output, which would handle pagination for you.  Note that this would likely require a pretty substantial refactoring effort, so depending on your situation it's likely not feasible, but it's an option.

It would also provide some potential flexibility down the road, as it provides a more modular approach. This would allow you to more easily provide other output options, like HTML & PDF. It may also make "print preview" easier.

Comment: Good one. I'm planning on designing a web portal, which provides customers the ability to log in and see/download invoices. This would provide an easy way to implement such options: my own answer would require some work in order to get the invoices printed on a website, whereas your option would probably provide an easy way to implement such functionalities in a website. I'm not going to mark your answer as the answer to my question just yet, I'm curious as to what other people think about this.